# Web scrape multiple links with r

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some tennis stats with r from multiple links using rvest and selectorgadget. Page I scrape from is http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/archive/stockholm/429/2017/results and there are 29 links that look like this: "http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/**MS001**/match-stats". All the links look the same but change from **MS001-MS029**. Using the below code I get the desired result with only the first 9 links. I see the problem but don't know how to correct it. First 9 links have double 00 and the rest have single 0. The 10th link should be MS010. Any help with this much appreciated.

```
library(xml)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

round <- 1:29
urls <- paste0("http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS00", round, 
"/match-stats")

aces <- function(url) {
url %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(".percent-on:nth-child(3) .match-stats-number-left span") %>%
html_text() %>% 
as.numeric()
}

results <- sapply(urls, aces)
results
$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS001/match-stats`
[1] 9

$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS002/match-stats`
[1] 8

$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS003/match-stats`
[1] 5

$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS004/match-stats`
[1] 4

$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS005/match-stats`
[1] 8

$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS006/match-stats`
[1] 9

$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS007/match-stats`
[1] 2

$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS008/match-stats`
[1] 9

$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS009/match-stats`
[1] 5

$`http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS0010/match-stats`
numeric(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can generate leading zeroes in a formatted string via the `sprintf()` function.

```
ids <- 1:29
urlList <- sapply(ids,function(x){     
sprintf("%s%03d%s","http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS",
         x,"/match-stats")
})
# print a few items
urlList[c(1,9,10,29)]
```

...and the output:

```
> urlList[c(1,9,10,29)]
[1] "http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS001/match-stats"
[2] "http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS009/match-stats"
[3] "http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS010/match-stats"
[4] "http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/2017/429/MS029/match-stats"
>
```

Comment: This works nicely, thank you. Actually 3 links MS016, MS020 and MS027 don't exist. May I follow up and ask if there is a way to scrape only the links that exist between 1:29?

Comment: sure, use ids <- c(1:15,17:19,21:26,28:29) to generate the URLs.

Comment: @mrsama - if you were able to use the solution I provided, please accept my answer.